# Developing a Thunderbird extension with C++

Tags: c++, xpcom, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Does anybody know any C++ tutorial for developing a thunderbird extension with XPCOM?

Comment: There are tutorials (mostly on MDN) for developing XPCOM components in C++, for developing Gecko extensions and for developing specifically Thunderbird extensions. But you still have to put them together, there are no tutorials for the exact scenario you are looking into. Btw, creating XPCOM components in C++ might not be the best idea: http://adblockplus.org/blog/binary-xpcom-components-are-dead-js-ctypes-is-the-way-to-go

Comment: @WladimirPalant Thunderbird's releases aren't as frequent as Firefox's.

Comment: @tstenner: They are, Thunderbird is using exactly the same rapid release cycle as Firefox. I am using Thunderbird 8 right now, based on Gecko 8. Firefox 9 and Thunderbird 9 are due to be released today, exactly 6 weeks after the previous release.

Comment: @WladimirPalant They are? I'm getting old...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Thunderbird Import Extension](http://www.felix-schwarz.name/Thunderbird_Import_Extension_(en)) is partially written in C++ and encourages developers who want to learn more about XPCOM to work on it.